# Twitter and Whatsapp sharing not showing image and description

Tags: twitter, meta-tags, whatsapp, twitter-share

I'm working on twitter and whatsapp share button that actually share the web pages. The Sharing of both working fine but the description and image not showing. I validated my twitter card through twitter card validator it showing perfect but while sharing it doesn't showing description and image and also whatsapp sharing, but facebook sharing that showing description and image. Thanks in advance.

Here is my meta tags:

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image">
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@site_username">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="Top 10 Things Ever">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="Up than 200 characters.">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@creator_username">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="yourdomain/image">
<meta name="twitter:domain" content="yourdomain">

<meta name="description" content="desc">
<meta property="og:title" content="title" />
<meta property="og:url" content="yourdomain" />
<meta property="og:description" content="description of your website/webpage">
<meta property="og:image" content="yourdomain/image">
<meta property="og:type" content="article" />
```

Here is my share buttons:

```
<a target="_blank" href="https://twitter.com/share?url=yourdomain&amp;text=Simple Text&amp;hashtags=hash"><i class="icon-twitter-stroke"></i></a>
<a target="_blank" href="whatsapp://send?text=yourdomain" data-action="share/whatsapp/share"><i class="icon-whatsapp"></i></a>
<a target="_blank" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=yourdomain"><i class="icon-facebook2"></i></a>
```

Comment: Are you specifying the full URL (including https://) to the image in the `twitter:image` tag? Have you run the URL through the Twitter card validator at https://cards-dev.twitter.com/validator to check that it works?

Comment: Yes,In twitter card validator working fine.

Comment: Is there a Tweet you've posted with the link where the card is not showing?

Comment: there is no tweet, but it is working fine in iOS

Comment: Ah do you mean that the card does not show in the web share dialog, but only after the Tweet is posted? That's expected behaviour. iOS shows the preview in the composer.

Comment: both part not showing

Comment: Can you share me a Tweet link where you've posted your link and "both parts are not showing"?